# Saving multiple objects from MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm writing my first MVC3 application which is a simple order tracking application. I would like to edit the order and the details at the same time. When I edit the order the ActionResult for the Edit returns the order and the associated line (i'm using EF as well).

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {            
        // Get the order with the order lines
        var orderWithLines = from o in db.Orders.Include("OrderLines")
                                where o.ID == id
                                select o;

        // Not sure if this is the best way to do this.
        // Need to find a way to cast to "Order" type
        List<Order> orderList = orderWithLines.ToList();
        Order order = orderList[0];

        // Use ViewData rather than passing in the object in the View() method.
        ViewData.Model = order;
        return View();            
    }
```

The order and the lines display with no issue but when I save the page I do not get any of the lines passed back to the controller. Only the order. Here is the View code.

```
    @model OrderTracker.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Order</legend>   

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>                   

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>
                <th>
                    Weight
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var line in Model.OrderLines)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => line.Description)
                </td> 
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => line.Quantity)
                </td> 
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => line.Weight)
                </td> 
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => line.Price)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p> 

    </fieldset>    
}
```

Can I please get some guidance on the best way to save the line data as well as the order data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue that you are facing is related to the names generated by the `ICollection<T>` controls. Here is a [detailed discussion by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and a solution by him (in terms of an **@Html extension method**; download the sample project from the link given at the end of his blog post). This post targets MVC/MVC2; however it is still applicable with MVC3.

Alternatively if you don't want to follow the hack, you can opt for a `EditorTemplate` for your `OrderLine` entity model.

**Here are the steps.**

**1)** Create Editor template under (`Views ->Shared -> EditorTemplates -> OrderLine.cshtml`)
It is important to create a folder named `EditorTemplates` under `Shared`, and the template name should be same as the EntityModel for which you want to create the templete; hence the name `OrderLine.cshtml`)

[image]

**2)** Code for OrderLine.cshtml

```
@model OrderTracker.Models.OrderLine
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.id)
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Description)
</td> 
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Quantity)
</td> 
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Weight)
</td> 
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Price)
</td>
</tr>
```

**3)** Edit your View with this code (note that I've used `EditorFor` for OrderLines collection)

```
@model OrderTracker.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Order</legend>   

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>                     
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>
                <th>
                    Weight
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
            </tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderLines)
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p> 

    </fieldset>    
}
```

**4)** Now on post back you will see the values

[image]

Comment: did not work in ASP MVC 5, any pointers please to send batch Ienumerable<Orders>

Comment: @transformer works fine in MVC5. What is failing for you? 'Order' model will have list of 'OrderLine' items. Pay close attention to points 1 & 3 in my answer. Do you have your sample code in a github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC it should be rather straight forward as the framework is designed to to turn a form into a model.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // (you can probably rewrite this using a lambda
    var orderWithLines = from o in db.Orders.Include("OrderLines")
                         select o;

    // Use ViewData rather than passing in the object in the View() method.
    ViewData.Model = orderWithLines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID = id);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderTracker.Models.Order model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // call the service layer / repository / db to persist the object graph
        _service.Save(model); // this assumes your view models are the same as your domain
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your foreach if you look at the raw html that it produces it will not be generating unique ids for each of the order lines and thus will not be able to bind the model when the form is posted back.

Change the foreach to a for loop and then reference each orderline using the index. This will allow for unique ids to be generated in the form and allow you to bind the to the model when it is posted back.

e.g.

```
@for (var counter = 0; counter < Model.OrderLines.Count(); counter++)

    { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[counter].Description)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[counter].Quantity)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[counter].Weight)
            </td> 
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[counter].Price)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Comment: I tried this and got an exception saying that I can't use an index with a collection. I inspected the HTML generated and can see that there are duplicate HTML element ID's for each line (not sure if this is a problem). So it looks like I need some other way of binding the view elements to the controller. What I do not understand is how the view binds to the controller. Does the view and controller match on the HTML element ID? Any links to a clear definition would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry should have been OrderLines not Orderlines. When you post back to the controller it will use the Id to bind the model - e.g. the item with the id "OrderLines_2__Description" is the description field for the second OrderLine.