# ASP.NET MVC EditorTemplate for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with 2 properties: `string` and `IEnumerable<SomeModel>`. If I specify editortemplate by `UiHint` for `string`, it is applied. But when I specify it for `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` property, nothing happens. Is there anything special that I need to do for IEnumerable?

Comment: There is no way to edit, in general, an IEnumerable<T>! What control would you use, if you know nothing about the actual properties?

Comment: @RicardoPeres, I know about SomeModel properties

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to replace your `IEnumerable` with `IList` and then use the following approach:

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    ...
    public IList<OrderLineDTO> Lines { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class OrderLineDTO
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    ...
    [Range(0, 1000)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    ...
}

...
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Lines.Count; ++i)
{
  ...
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Lines[i].Quantity)
  ...
}
...
```

Works with MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your HintTemplate model should be `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` (you will be iterating the model in the editor template). Alternatively instead of UIHint annotation you can use the EditorFor on the collection property (in this case EditorTemplate model will be SomeModel; there is no iteration involved in the view syntax). I've provided a similar reply [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167538/saving-multiple-objects-from-mvc-view/11174133#11174133)

If your Model looks like

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    [UIHint("HintTemplate")]
    public IEnumerable<TestChildModel> children { get; set; }
}
```

ChildModel

```
public class TestChildModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Your HintTemplate.cshtml should look like

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC3.Models.TestChildModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>HintTemplate</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach(var a in Model)
    {
    <div style="background-color:#4cff00">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => a.ChildName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => a.ChildName)
    </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Your view

```
@model MVC3.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.ParentName)
    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.ParentName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.children)
    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.children)
</div>
```