# create a dynamic page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm at a bit of a loss trying to work out how to create a dynamic (ie changing at run-time) web page - literally have no idea what the best way to go about this is.  The situation:

I am creating an ASP .NET MVC3 web application, and want to create a page where users are creating a `Tariff` object and adding `TariffBand` objects to `Tariff.Bands` - a list of TariffBand objects (class defs below).  Each band requires:

- a textbox for the lower limit
- a textbox for the upper limit
- a textbox for the unit rate

The user will enter the details of each TariffBand in the `/Tariff/Create` view, and ideally I want there to be a button on the page (`"Add another band"`) that will show another set of textboxes for the next band on the tariff.

I understand how to create the textboxes above, but I can't workout how I should edit the view file to meet the requirement above.  Should I be using some partial views?  Or using javascript to inject some HTML?

I'm not looking for any code particularly (although if you want to share some I would be indebted, but rather guidance on the best way to achieve this.  I am ok with razor/c# but n00b with javascript/jQuery.

My final question is: how does one assign values entered in textboxes etc to the view's model attributes without using the @Html.TextboxFor() methods?  Just curious if there is a way to do this.

Any help really appreciated, going little bit mad trying to Google this one!

**Tariff**

```
class Tariff
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public List<TariffBand> Bands {get; set}
}
```

**Tariff bands**

```
class TariffBands
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int UpperLimit  {get; set;}
    public int LowerLimit  {get; set;}
}
```

Many thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this using Non-Sequential Indices.

First, see general information about them in the [blog on Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

From the blog:

> ...we provide a hidden input with the .Index suffix for each item we
>   need to bind to the list. The name of each of these hidden inputs are
>   the same, so as described earlier, this will give the model binder a
>   nice collection of indices to look for when binding to the list

```html
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, once you understand the principal of this technique, there is a possibility of using html helper to build these:

I know about two versions of these helpers. It is up to you to chose one:

1. [Helper by Ivan Zlatev](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) (I prefer this one)
2. [Helper by Steven Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, you got me started on the right road!  Now if only I could get my javascript to be called!  One step at a time...

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide all of the code, but maving the models helps.

Use some jQuery to create the DOM elements on the client dynamically (i.e. the multiple tariff bands per tariff) with arrays (i.e. id of TariffBands[0].UpperLimit, etc.) to provide the ability to have multiple tariff bands added dynamically on the client.  When it POSTs the default binder will bind it to an array of TariffBands (provided you have the IDs correct on the client).

I do this with multiple file uploads (i.e. UploadedDocuments[0] would be the client name attribute then I can added as many inputs with that name with whatever index it is at the time and then iterate on the POST to save the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an `EditorTemplate` for `TariffBand` and use it in the view. Check my answer in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167538/saving-multiple-objects-from-mvc-view/11174133#11174133)